# Selection Sort Counting comparisons

Tags: c, selection-sort

i have a program with Selection Sort, which generates and sorts random numbers in ascending order and descending order. The problem is with the counting of comparisons. It gives correct number until 10 0000 numbers, but when i generate 100k numbers, it returns wrong value than the one from a formula.
Here is my Selection Sort code.

```
void select (int n, float *pole2,int *compare,int *move,char decide)
{
    *compare=0; // number of comparisons
    *move=0;

int i; 
     for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
     {                              
         int j, poz_min;
         float temp,min;
         min = pole2[i];
         poz_min = i;//
         for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
         {  
                *compare+=1;
                 if (pole2[j] < min)
                 {  
                    min = pole2[j];
                    *move+=1;
                    poz_min=j;
                 }  
         }
         temp = pole2[i];
         pole2[i] = pole2[poz_min];
         pole2[poz_min] = temp;
         *move+=3;
     }


// Writing to a binary file     

FILE *fw;
    fw = fopen("Select_SORT.DAT", "wb+");
int z;
for(z = 0; z < n; z++)
    {
        fwrite(&pole2[z], sizeof(pole2[z]), 1, fw);
    }
 fclose(fw);


 fseek(fw, 0, SEEK_SET);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that's because for `100K` there is actually `10^10` comparisons. An `int` on your system cant hold it. Try using `long long` to be safe. Also compare what you get with `INT_MAX`. You will get the idea.

For `n` elements there are `O(n^2)`(`n*(n-1)/2` to be precise) comparisons in case of selection sort.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance `int *compare` is capable of containing maximum value of 65536. 
Try `long`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types